# How to handle authentication along with captcha when crawling data using Scrapy

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy, web-crawler, recaptcha

I'm trying to crawl a bunch of text messages from a [website](https://www.chatwork.com/login.php) using [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) and i'm currently stuck in the authentication phase before i could carry out any crawling.

More specifically, i can not get through the login screen of the targeted website in which has a reCAPTCHA checkbox like in the below image. The problem is that it keep getting redirect back to the original login link along with validation error of the robot checkbox.

[image]

I've searched through all similar questions in the community and tried to go with the solution of copying cookies carrying my authenticated session from my browser (after i manually logged in) so that i can use them with Scrapy, but it still does not work.

Here is my code so far:

```
import ...

class CrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = "test"
allowed_domains = ["chatwork.com"]
start_urls = [
    "https://www.chatwork.com/#!rid178468980"
    #this is the link contains the data i want but only available after valid authentication
]

def start_requests(self):
    my_cookies = {
        'IDE': 'AHWqTUndZmIFDWBVb1ykpytLr0WAZOuBRQ8q363qEvII08rf3386rKljf4OVYIFp',
        #...some other lines copied from browser after manually logged in
    }
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
         Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'
    }

    for i, url in enumerate(self.start_urls):
        yield scrapy.Request(url, cookies=my_cookies, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    #... get data by scrapy Selector
    yield
```

Also i have tried another solution according to this article [here](https://dev.to/lewiskori/web-scraping-managing-proxies-and-captcha-with-scrapy-and-the-scraper-api-2c5b) in which i use the help of Scraper API as i thought it could somehow "handle" the reCAPTCHA, but still does not work.

Here is my code for the Scraper API way:

```
import ...

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):

  name = 'crawler_handle_captcha'
  url_link = "https://www.chatwork.com/login.php?args="
  API_KEY = '...'
  start_urls = ['http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=' + API_KEY + '&url=' + url_link + 
         '&render=true']

  def parse(self, response):

    return [FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formxpath='//form[@name="login"]',
        formdata={'email': 'sample@gmail.com', 'password': 'sample'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )]

  def after_login(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request(url="https://www.chatwork.com/#!rid178468980", 
           callback=self.parse_page)

  def parse_page(self, response):
        #... get data by scrapy Selector
        yield
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's no "easy" way to deal with recaptcha in scrapy.

But you can use captcha solving services like 2captcha to solve it using their API. 
It's paid service, but quite cheap.

When recaptcha will be solved by service you'll get the answer code, in order to login you'll have to create login request(usually it's POST request with login and password) and add solved captcha cookie to the request.